# Can we get tags in supersearch results?

Tags: solspace, supersearch

I am using EE (v 2.5.2),super search (v 2.0.8) and Tag module (v 4.2.3),I want to know if we can get the tags of any channel entries in search result?,if yes then how to do that because I was not able to find any documentation in getting tags in search results using SUPER SEARCH

Cheers
Nisar

Answer (score 1):

You can use any standard fieldtype, module, or plugin tags within Super Search results - use them just as you would within a `channel:entries` loop.

```
{exp:tag:tags entry_id="{entry_id}" backspace="1"}{tag}, {/exp:tag:entries}
```

Comment: Hi Derek,Thanks for the reply.Sorry that I could not reply to your comment,actually I want to search tags based on user input.For example if user types wood in search field then I would like to show all the tags containing word 'wood'.The expression you showed basically searches tag of a particular entry isn't?

Comment: Ah, that wasn't clear. So long as the Tag field is set to "searchable" in your field settings, then yes, Tags will be searched against your keywords as well.